# <layout_gravity="start"> doesn't work on NavigationView?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to make a Navigation Drawer, and inside the `NavigationView` I've added the `layout_gravity="start"` attribute, but it wont hide the View. this is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout  ... >

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"></android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What could be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: If you intend for the `NavigationView` to behave as a drawer, then the root `View` should be `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>`, instead of `<RelativeLayout>`.

Comment: @MikeM. it worked, thank you. please write this as answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend for the NavigationView to behave as a drawer, then the root View should be `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>`, instead of `<RelativeLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you because **layout_gravity** cannot be used inside **Relativelayout**.

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"></android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```